# Is Pageable.unpaged() in Spring JPA stress server?

Tags: spring, pagination

The paging in Spring JPA using Pageable. But idk I get page by by with size or Pageable.unpaged() which one has good performance

```
@GetMapping("/book")
public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getAllBooks(
    @org.springdoc.api.annotations.ParameterObject Pageable pageable
) {
    Page<Book> page = BookService.findAll(pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
}
```